# Difference between $\mathcal{N}=2$ and $\mathcal{N}=(1,1)$ SUSY

Tags: definition, notation, supersymmetry, superalgebra

In supersymmetry algebra, $\mathcal{N}$ refers to $I=1,2,.. \mathcal{N} $ in $Q^{I}_{\alpha}$. My question is what does it mean to write $\mathcal{N}=(1,1)$ superalgebra?

Comment: See e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Poincar%C3%A9_algebra#SUSY_in_various_dimensions).

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out the meaning of this after some research so, I am posting an answer to my own question.

The answer is there is nothing called $\mathcal{N}=(1,1)$ superalgebra. The superalgebra is always named by $\mathcal{N}$ with integers.

The $\mathcal{N}=(1,1)$ actually means a supergravity multiplet so my original question was wrong. We get this multiplet as the massless level of IIA superstring theory. (1,1) stands for getting fields of two different chiralities.